# How to pass item that was selected in a combobox of UserControl to the main window ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have a parent view with 3 RadioButtons and UserControl `MyDataSelector`. `MyDataSelector` consists of ComboBox and several other simple controls (CheckBox, Button, etc). ComboBox of MyDataSelector should be filled with different items depending on selected RadioButton on a parent view.

I'm using `MyDataSelector` in the XAML of my parent view:

```
<controls:MyDataSelector CurrentSelectedValue="{Binding InputElement}" DataContext="{Binding childViewModel}" />
```

where

1. `InputElement` - this is a string property in a parent ViewModel
   that I want to set when user selects something in ComboBox.
2. `childViewModel` - this is a ViewModel of my UserControl.
3. I defined  `CurrentSelectedValue` using DependencyProperty:

   ```
   public partial class MyDataSelector: UserControl
   {
         public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentSelectedValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentSelectedValue", typeof(String), typeof(MyDataSelector));

         public string CurrentSelectedValue
         {
              get {return GetValue(CurrentSelectedValueProperty).ToString(); }
              set {SetValue(CurrentSelectedValueProperty, value);
         }
   ....
   ```
4. Here's how ComboBox in MyDataSelector looks:

   `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelectedValue, ElementName=me}"/>`
5. `AvailableItems`- this is a `ObservableCollection<string>` that is populated with different elements depending on which RadioButton was checked in a parent view.
6. And `me` this is a Name of `MyDataSelector` UserControl: `<UserControl.... x:Name="me">`

Could anyone help me to find out why it doesn't work? I see that list of `AvailableItems` is loaded correctly and I can select any item in ComboBox, but getter or setter of `InputElement` property in my parent ViewModel is never called, so something is wrong with binding I believe :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `Two-Way Binding`?

```
<controls:MyDataSelector CurrentSelectedValue="{Binding InputElement, Mode=Two-Way}" 
    DataContext="{Binding childViewModel}" />
```

Please see the [Binding.Mode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for more help with this.